# How do I efficiently support both item- and collection-level locking?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an application has a collection of domain objects that need to be 
updated in real-time. Several threads can take action that modify the items in 
this collection and must do so safely. The current approach is rather 
simplistic, taking essentially a global lock before making any changes. 
More or less something like the following:

```
private readonly object lockObject = new object();
private Dictionary<int, Widget> items;

private void UpdateAllWidgets()
{
    lock (this.lockObject)
    {
        // Update all the widgets. No widgets should be permitted to be 
        // updated while this is running.
    }
}

private void UpdateWidget(int widgetId)
{
    lock (this.lockObject)
    {
        // Update the widget with id = widgetId. I want to me able to 
        // update other widgets at the same time, however.
    }
}
```

I am now running into problems with performance because the lock is too coarse.
I would like to be able to take item-level locks while a single item is being
updated (allowing other items to be updated at the same time), but still be able
to take a collection-level lock when necessary. So the behavior would look like
the following:

```
Thread 1: UpdateWidget(1);
Thread 2: UpdateWidget(2);  // This can run before UpdateWidget(1) 
                            // completes.

Thread 1: UpdateWidget(1);
Thread 2: UpdateAllWidgets();  // This has to wait for UpdateWidget(1)
Thread 3: UpdateWidget(2);  // This has to wait for UpdateAllWidgets()
Thread 4: UpdateWidget(3);  // This has to wait for UpdateAllWidgets(), but
                            // not UpdateWidget(2)
```

**Any ideas on a lock structure that would support this?** The example above is 
necessary a simplified version, but we have already ruled out 
ConcurrentDictionary has being insufficient. The actions taken in, for example, 
UpdateWidget, are more than just simple in-place updates. They could involve database updates that impact that item, etc.

Comment: I cumulate both approaches when I have this kind of scenario. A ConcurrentDictionary, but wraping each value into a container I can lock before making changes. You would need to add a global ReaderWriterLockSlim to handle the collection-level locking

Comment: Are items added to (or removed from) the collection in a multithreaded manner? Or the collection has static size and the elements are just updated?

Comment: @MatiasCicero- Yes, items can be added and removed from other threads. Adds should not block item-level updates; a removal would block that item only.

Comment: What would be the problem with having a lock per item used for modifying an item and using a `ConcurrentDictionary` for adding, updating and removing items (or uses your own lock for the collection)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefix my answer with the assumption that you have benchmarked this multithreaded behavior vs marshalling all work to a single thread. If not, please do- you may find it is much faster to avoid the lock contention entirely.

What you are looking for is a reader writer lock, probably [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net. To update a single item, [take a read lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterreadlock(v=vs.110).aspx), then `lock()` the item, do the update, and release the `lock()` and then the read lock. To do an "all items" update, an add, or a remove, [take a write lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterwritelock(v=vs.110).aspx), which will be exclusive.

Comment: I like it. It's creative and it does the job.